# Can't access a few websites, even after restarting the local router?

Tags: networking, router

I am unable to access the website https://expo.dev on my computer (and there was another website recently, the one everyone uses on StackOverflow for linking to TypeScript playgrounds using short URLs).

[image]

I just restarted my router. How can I debug why it's not working for me? I don't have any special settings as far as I know, like firewalls or anything like that. I just have the default AT&T internet.

I also tried connecting from my iPhone as a personal hotspot (when not connected to the wifi on the phone), and the website still doesn't work.

Hmm, I deselected "With your current service provider" in Chrome settings (I never changed any Chrome settings) and selected "Custom" and it works now, is that safe / the right approach?

[image]

Comment: Can you PING expo.dev from the command prompt?
Can you PING 104.18.4.104

I can resolve this IP
Pinging expo.dev [104.18.4.104] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 104.18.4.104: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=57

Comment: Get in touch with your ISP Support and ask what's their problem with `expo.dev `. One possible (but unlikely) theory is that the DNS of `expo.dev ` has changed recently and your ISP's DNS server was not up to date. Try it again tomorrow, as they should be updated at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Domain Name System (DNS) server or provider](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-a-dns-server/) is the service that looks up a website name, e.g., *microsoft.com*, and translates that into one of the IPv4 or IPv6 hosts for that site, e.g., 20.53.203.50.

If your internet service provider (ISP) has their own DNS server, it is apparently not finding some sites. In that case, tray an alternative DNS provider, such as [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-1.1.1.1/) or [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) (which you've tried). Each operating system, such as [Windows, Mac,](https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/how-to-change-dns-server-windows-mac) [Ubuntu](https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-set-dns-nameserver-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy/), or [Android](https://www.androidpolice.com/use-preferred-dns-server-android-tutorial/), has a method for setting the DNS provider. It might also help to clear the DNS cache of the device (not the router), or just reboot the device.

When selecting a DNS provider, look up reviews about the privacy of that service. For example, does the provider sell records of the sites you visit to advertisers? BTW, [MS Edge was leaking all URL's visited!](https://www.news18.com/tech/microsoft-edge-is-leaking-user-browsing-history-to-bing-api-site-report-7654117.html)

BTW, when using some public internet connections, e.g., at a library or in a hotel, you might need to revert to automatic DNS lookup if that connection blocks your chosen provider.